# How can I write these chemical reaction equations?

Tags: equations, chemistry

Trying to write a thesis, and I need some reaction equations. How can I write this in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: `\rightleftarrows`, `\underset{…}{…}` and `\overset{…}{…}` might be your friends.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple of packages for typesetting chemistry stuff, one such is `chemmacros`. The equation in your image can be typeset as

```
\ch{S + E <>[ $k_{\mathrm{SI}}$ ][ $k_{\mathrm{IS}}$ ] E.I <>[ $k_{\mathrm{PI}}$ ][ $k_{\mathrm{IP}}$ ] P + E}
```

which will give

[image]

I suggest you take a look at the manual for the package. It is probably installed along with the package in your TeX distribution, and you can find it by writing `texdoc chemmacros` in a command prompt/terminal (or in the search field in the start menu, if you're on Windows). Or you can get it at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\ch{S + E <>[ $k_{\mathrm{SI}}$ ][ $k_{\mathrm{IS}}$ ] E.I <>[ $k_{\mathrm{PI}}$ ][ $k_{\mathrm{IP}}$ ] P + E}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually found a simpler method, but this is very useful.  I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Ups, this is a great answer, I missed the {chemistry} label in my comment.

Comment: @DemetriP Please write up your simpler way as an answer. It's fine to answer your own questions: one of the goals of the site is to build up a repository of good answers to questions so that other people can use the answers too.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following code to write the equation

```
S+E  \xrightleftharpoons[k_{IS}]{k_{SI}}  I \cdot E \xrightleftharpoons[k_{PI}]{k_{IP}} P+E
```

the `\xrightleftharpoons` allows you to specify what goes on top/bellow of the arrows.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand.